# Python logging file config with variable directory

Tags: python, logging, configparser

I'm using Python logging and loading it with `logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)`, from e.g. `logging.cfg`. It contains a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`. It works great. For a long time it has been using (simplied):

```
[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
formatter=complex
level=DEBUG
args=('logs/logging.log', 'midnight')
```

Now I want to make the logging directory (`logs` above) configurable, but still use the configuration file, e.g. `logging.cfg`.

I was hoping to somehow inject/string interpolate in a variable e.g. `log_directory` to just do:

```
args=('%(log_directory)s/logging.log', 'midnight')
```

Or since logging does an eval maybe something like:

```
args=(f'{log_directory}/logging.log', 'midnight')
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple. How can I best do this, while still using a configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify defaults in the `fileConfig()` call:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.cfg', defaults={
    'log_directory': 'foo/logs'
}, disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

along with

```
args=('%(log_directory)s/logging.log', 'midnight')
```

Of course, make sure the directory you specify exists and is writable.